# Alternative for laravel config() in vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm refactoring laravel and vue inline templates app and I see a lot of `config()` functions. Has anyone figured how to use it in vue normal components?

I saw that it is possible to access env with `process.env`

Also translation configs has solution with i18n package. Maybe there is solution for `app/config` files?

Answer (score 0):

The configurations in `app/config` are specifically used for back end purposes. I'm not aware if there are any packages that allow you to do this as of writing. A quick google on this doesn't show any thing as well (Might be a good opportunity to create a package for).

Yes you can access your `env` variables by using `process.env` but make sure they are prefixed with `MIX_` as mentioned in [Laravel - Compiling Assets](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix#environment-variables).

So say you have this in your `.env`:

```
MIX_FOO=bar
FOO=bar
```

You can access them in your js with:

```
process.env.MIX_FOO // bar
process.env.FOO // undefined
```

Also, making changes to the `.env` file will not be read once you have compiled you assets, you'll need to recompile them to take changes.